# 'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat' SwiftUI Misleading error

Tags: json, struct, swiftui, func

I am trying to call a function I have made which pulls data from an API. The function is created before the `var body: some View` part and is call inside of that. There are no compiler errors in the function itself or anywhere else. Before I started to use SwiftUI I had no issue with this type of function and the code is almost the exact same. Here is the code for the function including the Struct I have for the JSON data;

```
var postDetailsData = postDetails.self
   var commentsArray = comments.self

   struct postDetails: Decodable {
       let count: Int?
       var results: [results]
   }
       struct results: Decodable {
           var id: String
           let author: author?
           let anonym: Bool
           let subscribed: Bool
           let created: String
           let active: Bool
           let text: String
           let image: String?
           let comments: [comments]
           
       }
           struct author: Decodable {
               let user: Int
               var name: String
               let avatar: String?
               let banned: Bool
           }
           struct comments: Decodable, Identifiable {
               let id: Int
               let text: String
               let author: authorOfComment?
           }
               struct authorOfComment: Decodable {
                   let name: String
                   let avatar: String?
       }

//And now the actual function

  let tokenData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedToken")

   var spread = Bool()
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/areas/sample/")! as URL,
                                           cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                           timeoutInterval: 10.0)

  func pullData(){
          let headers = [
              "Authorization": "token \(tokenData ?? "nope")",
              "cache-control": "no-cache",
              "Postman-Token": "53853353-f547-410a-b289-e3c4ced8e426"
          ]
          
          request.httpMethod = "GET"
          request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
          
          let session = URLSession.shared
          let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
              if (error != nil) {
                  print(error)
              }
              guard let data = data else {return}
              
              do{
                  let JSONFromServer = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                  print(JSONFromServer)
                  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                  decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                  let postDetailsDataArray = try decoder.decode(postDetails.self, from: data)
                  print(postDetailsDataArray.results)
                  for results in postDetailsDataArray.results{
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                          //Account Pic Post and Other Stuff In The HStack
                    let accountPicAndStuff =  HStack {
                       
                       
                       Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                               ImageWithActivityIndicator(imageURL: results.author?.avatar ?? "")
                               .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                               .clipShape(Circle())
                               .offset(x: -75, y: 0)
                           }
                           
                           Text(results.author?.name ?? "Annon")
                               .offset(x: -75)
                           Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                            Image("BookMark").offset(x: 70)
                           }
                           Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                            Image("more-vertical").offset(x: 70)
                           }
                           
                       }.offset(y: 65)
                       
                       //accountPicAndStuff.offset(y: 65)
                       
                          //Description code (pulls data from api)
                          
                          var postTextTest = results.text
                          
                       Text(results.text)
                       //.padding(.bottom, 0)
                       .offset(y: 10)
                       .lineLimit(4)
                       
                       //Image From Post Stuff
                       if results.image == nil{
                           print("no image")
                       }else{
                       ImageWithActivityIndicator(imageURL: results.image ?? "")
                       .offset(y: 50)
                       .scaledToFit()
                       }
                          //Date and time for post
                       Text(results.created)
                           .font(.footnote)
                           .fontWeight(.light)
                           .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                           .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                           .offset(x: -85, y: 50)
                          
                          for comments in results.comments{
                              print(comments)
                                  //Comment View Code using Lists
                           
                           List(results.comments){ comments in
                               HStack{
                                   ImageWithActivityIndicator(imageURL: comments.author?.avatar ?? "")
                                   .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                               }
                            }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }catch{
                  print("Failed to decode:", error)
              }
          })
          dataTask.resume()
      }
```

This is how I call the function;

```
struct FunAreaSmall: View {

//Code from above goes here...

    var body: some View {
        //Smaller UI
                       VStack {
                       pullData()
                        
                           HStack {
                                      Button(action:{}) {
                                       Image("SkipBtn")
                                           .offset(y: 60)
                                           .scaledToFit()
                                      }
                                   Button(action: {}) {
                                       Image("IgniteBtn")
                                           .offset(y: 60)
                                           .scaledToFit()
                               }
                           }
                }
        }
    
    }
```

The error itself,

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat'

appears on `.offset(y: 60)` on the first button in the HStack which I know isn't the issue because when I comment out the call to the function, the error goes away. I have tried different ways of doing getting around this error but all I get is more errors. I have tried to look up the errors on google and nothing has helped yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put function call in a `ViewBuilder`, because it can't resolve opaque return type.

There are several possible solutions, depending on your needs:

1) Put call of `pullData` in `init()` 
2) Provide explicit return in `ViewBuilder` (all of them) 
3) Call in some closure (seems most appropriate in this use-case) as in below:

```
struct FunAreaSmall: View {

    //Code from above goes here...
    var body: some View {
        //Smaller UI
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action:{}) {
                    Image("SkipBtn")
                        .offset(y: 60)
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image("IgniteBtn")
                        .offset(y: 60)
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            self.pullData()
        }
    }
}
```